# Too frequent API fetch with setInterval() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, setinterval

I have a problem with my React project. I have a basic SelectList with milli seconds and based on that I want to set the interval of setInterval. The thing is, it looks like it doesn't change the interval and the API calls seems too fast. The basic value is 1 minute. Here is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        FetchData();
        

        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          FetchData();
        }, Interval)


        return() => clearInterval(interval);

    },[Interval])


    const handleChangeInInterval = (event) =>{
      console.log("Changed interval to: ", event.target.value);
      setInterval(event.target.value)
    }


    const FetchData = async () =>{
      const resp = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/stock/getcandle/AAPL/1")
            console.log(resp);
            const formattedData = formatData(resp.data.candleDataList);
            console.log(formattedData);
            setStockData(formattedData);
            console.log("fetch called");
    }
```

Comment: did you name your state setting function `setInterval` ?

Comment: haha, @azium that must be it. Please add the rest of the component, any state or where the `Interval` var is coming from

Comment: @azium it was indeed :D Thank you very much saved my from pulling my hair all night, thanks!